# NameError: uninitialized constant for sidekiq worker in production but works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, nameerror

I'm setting up a background task with sidekiq and redis. Have it working completely fine in development, but when testing on staging site I get:

> NameError: uninitialized constant InviteWorker::User

/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def invite
  params[:user] ? @user = User.where(:referral_code => params[:user])[0] : @user = User.find_by_email(cookies[:h_email])
  user_id = @user.id
  content = params[:body]
  emails = params[:email].split(',')
  total_emails = emails.length
  user_email = @user.email
  referral_code = @user.referral_code
  cloudsponge_emails = params[:count_cloudsponge]
  tracked_count = false
  InviteWorker.perform_async(content, emails, total_emails, user_email, referral_code, cloudsponge_emails, tracked_count, user_id)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

/app/workers/invite_worker.rb

```
class InviteWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker

def perform(content, emails, total_emails, user_email, referral_code, cloudsponge_emails, tracked_count, user_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  emails.each_with_index do |email,index|
    email = email.gsub(/\s+/, '')
    if email.include? '<'
      email = email.split('<')[1].split('>')[0]
    end
    if User.where(:email => email).empty? && EmailInvite.where('created_at >= ?', Time.now.beginning_of_day).where(:email => email).empty? && User.new.verify_email(email)
      UserMailer.invite_email(content, email, user_email, referral_code).deliver_now
      if index == 0 || tracked_count == false
        EmailInvite.create(:user => user, :email => email, :count => total_emails)
        tracked_count = true
      else
        EmailInvite.create(:user => user, :email => email)
      end
    end
  end
end

end
```

/config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/workers
  #{config.root}/lib
)

config.eager_load_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/workers
  #{config.root}/lib
)
```

Procfile

```
web:     bundle exec puma -C ./config/puma.rb
worker:  bundle exec sidekiq -e $RACK_ENV -r ./config/sidekiq.rb -c ${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY:-5}
```

Edit - error message provided:

```
4 TID-u31nw InviteWorker JID-ea609b6557e45a4d299dcde7 INFO: start 
4 TID-u31nw InviteWorker JID-ea609b6557e45a4d299dcde7 INFO: fail: 0.002 sec 
4 TID-u31nw WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"InviteWorker","args":["Hey, join me and sign up!",["email@umd.edu"],1,"email@gmail.com","68QBZ","0",false,2945],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"ea609b6557e45a4d299dcde7","created_at":1531780015.902798,"enqueued_at":1531780015.9035575},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"InviteWorker\",\"args\":[\"Hey, join me and sign up!\",[\"email@umd.edu\"],1,\"email@gmail.com\",\"68QBZ\",\"0\",false,2945],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"ea609b6557e45a4d299dcde7\",\"created_at\":1531780015.902798,\"enqueued_at\":1531780015.9035575}"} 
4 TID-u31nw WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant InviteWorker::User 
4 TID-u31nw WARN: /app/app/workers/invite_worker.rb:5:in `perform' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:187:in `execute_job' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in process' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:168:in `block in process' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:139:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:98:in `local' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:138:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:36:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:134:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:199:in `stats' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:129:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/job_logger.rb:8:in `call' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb:73:in `global' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `block in dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:48:in `with_context' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:42:in `with_job_hash_context' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `dispatch' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:167:in `process' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:85:in `process_one' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:73:in `run' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-5.1.3/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: What version of ruby are you running locally? On heroku? Where is the error message coming from (can you share the backtrace?).

Comment: Everything in /app is automatically loaded.  Remove /app/workers from your `config/application.rb` paths. In Rails, editing any paths is a very bad idea.

Comment: @bm5k ruby 2.3.0 both locally and on heroku. error message added in original post above

Comment: I asked about the ruby version because ruby recently changed the way top-level constant lookups work. I don't think that applies to ruby ~> 2.3 though. Are you sure that's the version running on heroku? Anyway, it seems like your constant lookup is being namespaced. Try using `::User` to prevent the namespacing.

Comment: @MikePerham I removed /app/workers and updated the ::User to prevent namespacing issue and am now just getting: NameError: uninitialized constant User

Comment: @BM5k now just getting NameError: uninitialized constant User .. so seems to have fixed namespacing issue but not recognizing User model still

Comment: This is the best info I have: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#autoloading

Comment: @MikePerham Thanks, I solved it by removing -r ./config/sidekiq.rb in the procfile

Comment: This is the single most aggravating problem I've ever had with Sidekq. It happens only in our staging environment. And I know that supposedly "It's Rails' fault" but the evidence does NOT bear that out. It is definitely a Sidekiq issue, or the way Sidekiq is using Rails. There are NO errors in web or console with these classes, but ALWAYS NameErrors in Sidekiq.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just restarted Sidekiq on production and it fixed a problem: `sudo service sidekiq restart`

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in 'namespace' parameter for redis in application.yml try to write it and reload redis, sidekiq and server

redis:
    url: redis://localhost:6379/1
    namespace: "some_namespace_name"

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with the eager_load or autoload paths. If you are using puma with many workers then you need to call these below the workers number in your config/puma.rb

```
workers 2
preload_app! #used when workers are more than 0
```